# Importing arcpy with reticulate

Tags: python, r, arcpy, reticulate

I wish to import the `arcpy` library in R using `reticulate`.

I tried running this code in R:

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.4")
arcpy = import("arcpy")
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  object 'arcpy' not found
```

I'm not entirely sure how Python goes about finding its modules (apparently it searches PYTHONPATH, but I don't know where this is defined).

I do understand that the `arcpy` library is actually in a different folder. Doing a bit of digging, I think I found it, so I tried this in R:

```
arcpy = import_from_path("arcpy", path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/Desktop10.4/ArcPy/arcpy")
```

But got the following error:

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'gp'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/Desktop10.4/ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
```

So I'm not too sure what's going on here, but I get the impression it has to do with Python or `reticulate` not looking in the right place for the right files?

Comment: (First) argument to `import` should probably be a string, not an object which doesn't exist. Try `import("arcpy")`.

Comment: Oops, sorry this is a transcription error. I have indeed been using `import("arcpy")`, but the problem occurs anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the full path to the `Python.exe` file within `C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.4`. In addition, use `required = TRUE`, so reticulate know that it has to use the provided python version.

If it resides directly in that folder, then

```
library(reticulate)

use_python("C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.4/Python.exe", required = TRUE)

arcpy <- import("arcpy")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This has produced a new error message:
`Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : Your current architecture is 64bit however this version of Python is compiled for 32bit.`
Does this mean I need to run a 32 bit version of R?

Comment: Yes, try that, or install a 64bit version of `arcpy`.